# Any way to batch resize png's canvas size keeping the image top left, but making the size divisible by 12

Tags: image-processing

We need to have huge amounts of png's resized to be divisible by 12, each png is variable in size and the image needs to stay 1:1 in the top left.

At the moment were having to manually bring in each file into Photoshop and enlarge the canvas on the x+y to be divisible by 12 and keep the image in the top left corner. With the amount of png's we need doing now and in future we need an automated process.

Comment: Yes, you do. What keeps you from creating a script to automate it?

Comment: "Yes, you do. What keeps you from creating a script to automate it?"

Comment: Our lazy programmers, I'm an artist trying to solve it and don't really have any script experience, I've been left in the dark how to automate this so proving a nightmare. 
I'm basically searching the net trying to find an easy method.

Comment: Well, you'll probably have the same problem here too, it is not very likely that somebody will write such a program for you here. The questions here are more like "I am writing this code and have this problem with my code - how do I fix it?" and not "Can somebody please write this program or suggest a link?". It is also difficult because we don't know anything about your system: OS, programs, libraries, and so on.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input. I'm literally clutching at straws and have been googling for most of the day trying to find any sort of image resizing software/Photoshop script possible and thought someone may have come across something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with ImageMagick, which is free and installed on most Linux distros and also available for OSX and Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org).

This little `bash` script will resize all the PNG files in the current directory and save them with the original name in the subdirectory called `output`. It is pretty easy to read - it basically loops through all the PNG files in the directory. It then uses ImageMagick's built-in calculator to work out the size of your output file as nearest multiple of 12. Then it loads the image and extends the background using transparent pixels (`-background none`) to that size (using `-extent`) and leaves the original image in the top-left corner (`-gravity NorthWest`).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make output directory - ignore errors
mkdir output 2> /dev/null

# Make sure we don't barf if there are no files
shopt -s nullglob

# Make sure we process *.png, *.PNG, *.pNg etc
shopt -s nocaseglob

# Loop through all pngs in current directory
for f in *.png; do

    # Calculate new extent as nearest multiple of 12
    # In general, to round x to nearest n, you do ((x+n-1)/n)*n
    extent=$(convert "$f" -format "%[fx:12*round(((w+11)/12)-0.5)]x%[fx:12*round(((h+11)/12)-0.5)]" info: )

    # Now extend canvas transparently to new size and leave original image in top-left
    convert "$f" -background none -gravity northwest -extent $extent output/"$f"
done
```

P.S. If installing `ImageMagick` on OSX, please ask for advice before trying.

P.P.S. If you have 10,000+ images to resize, and you do it often, and you are on OSX or Linux (probably not Windows), I would recommend `GNU Parallel`. If that is likely, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, this is a possible solution for your problem. This script will run in [MATLAB](http://mathworks.com/products/matlab/) or [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (Octave is an open-source alternative to MATLAB, so you might want to use that.)

Copy the following function into a file and call it `resizeIm.m`. Then start Octave and call this function for every image you have.

```
function resizeIm(fileName)
    % Read image
    origIm = imread(fileName);

    % Get size and calculate new size
    origSize = size(origIm);
    div = ceil(origSize ./ 12);

    % Create new, padded image
    newIm = zeros(12*div,class(origIm));
    newIm(1:origSize(1),1:origSize(2)) = origIm;

    % Write image to new file
    [dir, name, ext] = fileparts(fileName);
    newFileName = [dir,name,"_resized",ext];
    imwrite(newIm,newFileName);
end
```

The function can be called by

```
resizeIm("C:\path\to\file\myimage.png")
```