# Increase image canvas by a number divisible by N

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image of certain dimensions, say WxH. My goal is to increase its canvas size (without scaling an image) to such dimensions W'xH' that W' is divisible by arbitrary N and H' is divisible by arbitrary M, yet both are least possible s.t. W'>=W and H'>=H.

I've searched through tons of docs but it seems like I didn't define perfectly what I'm looking for.

Comment: What language are you expecting to use? I.M. truly is a swiss-army knife, but you would be expected to implement the high-level business logic to calculate the `W'xH'` that meets such requirements.

Comment: This is a similar question that may help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988129/2836621

Comment: @emcconville `ffmpeg` has it: `If one of the values is -n with n > 1, the scale filter will also use a value that maintains the aspect ratio of the input image, calculated from the other specified dimension. After that it will, however, make sure that the calculated dimension is divisible by n and adjust the value if necessary.` https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but I'm sure there's plenty of other techniques.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

N=4
M=5
FILENAME="rose:"

WIDTH=$(identify -format %w "${FILENAME}" | awk -v N=$N '{ m = $1 % N; d = int($1 / N) + 1; printf "%d", (m==0)? $1 : d * N}')
HEIGHT=$(identify -format %h "${FILENAME}" | awk -v M=$M '{ m = $1 % M; d = int($1 / M) + 1; printf "%d", (m==0)? $1 : d * M}')

convert "${FILENAME}" -extent "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}" /tmp/output.png
```

This works by reading the `FILENAME` metrics, and calculates the *next* arbitrary divisibility with awk -- if not already divisible. Than pass the new width/height to [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent) operator which will increase the canvas size without resizing/scaling the image. The [`-gravity`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) can also be used to control centering & alignment.